# Getting a 403 forbidden error when trying to add a JDBC secondary user store in WSO2 APIM 3.2.0

Tags: wso2-api-manager

I am getting a 403 forbidden error when trying to add a JDBC secondary user store in WSO2 APIM 3.2.0 from the carbon console. Though the connection is healthy on clicking the test button, but unable to add the user store. Any hints or suggestions to resolve this issue is appreciated.

Thanks,
Suman

Answer (score 0):

I think need check server policy and permissions or application path .... because the HTTP 403 Forbidden response status code indicates that the server understands the request but refuses to authorize it.

Comment: How and where can we check these things - the server policy, permissions or application path?

Comment: see sequences error codes
https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.2.0/troubleshooting/error-handling/#api-handlers-error-codes

Comment: check this error code: 900906, 900908, 900910

Comment: Hi, I checked and understand that getting a 403 forbidden error. How can I fix this?